# How to get all fonts used on a page using node.js?

Tags: node.js, cheerio, jsdom

I need to crawl all the pages on a site (the crwling part works fine.) and so i need to run **[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8793011/4381665)** script on my server using node.js. I tried implementing the following logic:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var URL = require('url-parse');
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
var { JSDOM } = jsdom;

var START_URL = "http://balneol.com/";
var SEARCH_FONT = "helvetica";
var MAX_PAGES_TO_VISIT = 100000;

var pagesVisited = {};
var numPagesVisited = 0;
var pagesToVisit = [];
var url = new URL(START_URL);
var baseUrl = url.protocol + "//" + url.hostname;

pagesToVisit.push(START_URL);
crawl();

function crawl() {
  if(numPagesVisited >= MAX_PAGES_TO_VISIT) {
    console.log("Reached max limit of number of pages to visit.");
    return;
  }
  var nextPage = pagesToVisit.pop();
  if (nextPage in pagesVisited) {
    // We've already visited this page, so repeat the crawl
    crawl();
  } else {
    // New page we haven't visited
    visitPage(nextPage, crawl);
  }
}

function visitPage(url, callback) {
  // Add page to our set
  pagesVisited[url] = true;
  numPagesVisited++;

  // Make the request
  console.log("Visiting page " + url);
  request(url, function(error, response, body) {
     // Check status code (200 is HTTP OK)

     console.log("Status code: " + response.statusCode);
     if(response.statusCode !== 200) {
       callback();
       return;
     }
     // Parse the window.document body
    //  var window  = jsdom.jsdom(body).defaultView();

    var { window } = new JSDOM(body);

     //var $ = cheerio.load(body);
     var helveticaFound = searchForHelvetica(window, 'font-family');
     if(helveticaFound) {
       console.log('Word ' + SEARCH_FONT + ' found at page ' + url);
     } else {
       collectInternalLinks($);
       // In this short program, our callback is just calling crawl()
       // callback();
     }
  });
}

function searchForHelvetica( window , css) {

    if(typeof getComputedStyle == "undefined")
    getComputedStyle= function(elem){
        return elem.currentStyle;
    }
    var who, hoo, values= [], val,
    nodes= window.document.body.getElementsByTagName('*'),
    L= nodes.length;

    for(var i= 0; i<L; i++){
        who= nodes[i];

        console.log(nodes[i]);

        if(who.style){
            hoo= '#'+(who.id || who.nodeName+'('+i+')');

            console.log(who.style._values);

            // return false;

            val= who.style.fontFamily || getComputedStyle(who, '')[css];
            if(val){
                if(verbose) values.push([hoo, val]);
                else if(values.indexOf(val)== -1) values.push(val);
                // before IE9 you need to shim Array.indexOf (shown below)
            }
        }
    }

    // console.log(values);

    // return values;

}

function collectInternalLinks($) {
    var relativeLinks = $("a[href^='/']");
    console.log("Found " + relativeLinks.length + " relative links on page");
    relativeLinks.each(function() {
        pagesToVisit.push(baseUrl + $(this).attr('href'));
    });
}
```

If you see my visit page function you will see the below two lines of code:

```
var { window } = new JSDOM(body);
var helveticaFound = searchForHelvetica(window, 'font-family');
```

as you can see on the 2nd line i am passing the `window` object to the `searchForHelvetic` function.

In my `searchForHelvetic` function , if i `console.log(nodes[i]);` , i don't get the html element and hence the rest of the script does't quite run as expected. does the jsdom `window` differ from the `window` object in the browser ? how do i get the script working ? I.E. basically use the window object to run through all the pages on the page and spit out all the fonts used on the page ?

**EDIT::-**
To break the problem down to a micro level, if i `console.log(who);` inside `searchForHelvetica` function , i get the following result:

```
HTMLElement {}
HTMLDivElement {}
HTMLDivElement {}
HTMLDivElement {}
HTMLAnchorElement {}
HTMLImageElement {}
HTMLDivElement {}
HTMLFormElement {}
HTMLDivElement {}
HTMLLabelElement {}
HTMLInputElement {}
HTMLButtonElement {}
HTMLButtonElement {}
HTMLSpanElement {}
```

etc..

But if i were to do the same in a web browser the result world be different Eg.

```
nodes = window.document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
console.log(node[1]) // <div id="mobile-menu-box" class="hide">...</div>
```

How do i get a similar result in node.js ?

Comment: Could you modularize this code more, define individual functions, each with a specific purpose, instead of having one sprawling function that does everything in one shot? It's not clear where the problem is, or even where to start looking. "Working" isn't a well defined objective. What do you need this to do? Can you break it down into a series of smaller problems?

Comment: @tadman sorry about that , basically i need `searchForHelvetica` function to return all the fonts used on the page , so i believe that's where you would need to start looking. the function would work fine in a browser console ,  but does't in node.js

Comment: @tadman edit added ! :)