# How to get list of all included fonts into the page?

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

List of all fonts (**not font-family**) that page loads from everywhere (font-face, google fonts, etc.). I wanna make it automatically, so I'm gonna write JS script for it if it is available.

Comment: do you want to get all fonts from a random website or one of your own ? in chrome you can look at the network tab in dev tools and filter for fonts

Comment: @Dirk I wanna use this script on any website and do it automatically (no manual clicking in DevTools)

Comment: May be this is what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792085/script-to-find-all-fonts-used-on-a-page

Comment: @Nik I noticed that I'm looking for font-faces, not font-family

Comment: sounds like you would to have to parse all css files and style tags.

Comment: @Dirk I guess yes :) any ideas?)